# How to check for suspicious logins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation, ip

So to avoid this question being too broad, I'm going to give the approaches/background used in my exact case, but feel free to provide general approaches to solve this problem as it's still helpful.

### Purpose

It may be a bit overkill, but large tech companies such as Google will notify their users if they suspect a login to that account to be suspicious. I've also known it to happen where a website will block a correct login attempt if it seems suspicious, for example: logging into an account in India that has never logged in from outside the US. For certain websites, people want this level of overwatch and protection.

### Background

I have a NodeJS express project that uses [iplocation](https://github.com/roryrjb/iplocation) and saves the ip data as well as the user agent to a database to track latest logins. **I'm trying to find a way detect suspicious logins based on location**, and then notify the user or take appropriate action in extreme cases.

Here is an example of a login record stored:

```
"ip" : {
    "ip" : "86.149.49.121",
    "country_code" : "GB",
    "country_name" : "United Kingdom",
    "region_code" : "ENG",
    "region_name" : "England",
    "city" : "Harwich",
    "zip_code" : "CO12",
    "time_zone" : "Europe/London",
    "latitude" : 51.95,
    "longitude" : 1.3,
    "metro_code" : 0
},
"ua" : {
    "version" : "61.0.3163.100",
    "source" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36",
    "os" : "macOS Sierra",
    "browser" : "Chrome"
},
"timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-01T02:00:45.452Z"),
"__v" : 0
```

### Approaches

1. **User Agent Check** - On very weak case. I could check and compare the User Agent (`browser`, `os`) to see if a different device is used. But as we all know people don't just use one device so I don't really see this been effective or useful.
2. **Country/Region Check** - A better approach I found, is to check the country (or for more accurate results, region). If there's a new country/region that doesn't match the standard then this would be suspicious. But this could include false positives such as if you live on a border of two countries.
3. **Long/Lat Range Check** - Finally I thought a better approach would be to see if the user is relatively near to their average long/lat. As this allows for people to be in nearby countries if they live close to the border but doesn't rely on checking every country name for it's neighbours.

Code Example:

```
var withinLongitude, withinLatitude;

// check if within 1 degree of latitude (about 69 miles either side)
if (loginAttempt.lat > (avgLat - 1) && loginAttempt.lat < (avgLat + 1) ) {
    withinLongitude = true;
}

// check if within 1 degree of longitude (usually more than 50 miles, at most 69 miles either side)
if (loginAttempt.lon > (avgLon - 1) && loginAttempt.lon < (avgLon + 1) ) {
    withinLatitude = true;
}

if (withinLongitude && withinLatitude) {
    // assume a normal login, handle login process
} else {
    // could be a suspicious login, email user
}
```

Obviously IP checks aren't always reliable and a user could be using a VPN, but what do you think. **Is this reliable enough to work or should I be thinking about this differently?**

Comment: Lat/Long is going to be very misleading. Often a national mobile provider will have all their addresses associated with their headquarters which could be thousands of miles away. You should run this against your user logs to see what the login patterns of your actual users are.

Comment: @tadman Assuming that the avgLon and avgLat is based upon the login patterns of the user (in this example, the mobile provider hq) - then they would always be within this area. I did think about doing multiple comparisons based upon browser, os, and geolocation.

Comment: It's pretty common for people to sign-in from work, mobile, home, and for good measure, the coffee-shop WiFi if not the WiFi on the subway/train/bus as well. This can create a pretty confusing pattern of data. I bet you have a few wild edge-cases in your user data you can use to determine the maximum extent of an actual real-world user.

Comment: @tadman yes that's true, I'm trying to think of reliable ways of checking for that the user is near home (and not someone who shouldn't have access). If the user's login patterns on a website are too broad then I could always extend the long/lat degrees so that it becomes 138 miles instead of 69 miles.

Comment: Collect data first, decide second. You're shooting in the dark here but I bet you're sitting on a gold-mine of data if you have a collection of user activity logs.